# How can i use Redux in my FullStack React Express App?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building Weather FullStack App with React and Express. I have user registration and login, and ofc main page with search city to see weather info.. I know it's to small app maybe for use Redux but i just want to try it. So it's my question what data (state) i can store in my redux in this app?

Comment: You need to be more specific because we don't know anything about your app, what do your express got some datas and which ones will you need in your react app ?

Comment: state is state. whatever you're calling `useState` for now you can swap for redux and vice versa